# Is there any analytical proof for this hyperbolic tangent equation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $$f(z_c,m) = \int_{-\infty}^a \frac{a^3 \tanh[m*(z+z_c)]}{8z^5} dz + \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{a^3 \tanh[m*(z+z_c)]}{8z^5} dz + \int_{-a}^a \frac{z\tanh[m*(z+z_c)]}{8a^3} dz$$
where $a$ is a constant which is greater than 0. Then $$g(m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z_c) d z_c$$ Numerical results show g(m) is a constant. Could we analytically prove that for any $m$, $g(m)$ is a constant? I have proved that $f(z_c)$ is an even function. Also I have tried to prove the $g'(m) = 0$, but then I got stuck because I have to deal with the integration of $\frac{\tanh^2 [m*(z + z_c)]}{z^{4}}$ or $z*\tanh^2 [m*(z + z_c)]$. Is there any other method?